# CameraX - how to handle front camera imageProxy rotation to have output bitmap always in portrait mode

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, rotation

I use CameraX and case analysse to receive bitmap to further processing. My Activity is blocked to portrait mode only.

Init analysse case:

```
       imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888)
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(720, 480)) 
                .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(getExecutor(), this);



   public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
...
}
```

How to get correct orientation for returned imageProxy? I'd like to to rotate returned image/bitmap to only portrait mode, never mind how phone is rotated by user. How to read correct rotation and finally set correct matrix value for output bitmap to have always portrait mode?

I use OrientationEventListener. It returns degree value so I can rotate bitmap after observing rotated imageProxy from front camera but there are phones which return other rotation degree for returned image and my way doesn't work.

imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees() always return 270 for front camera. How it is possible? I rotate phone and it still return 270? Please note my Activity is locked in portrait mode.

I suppose it should be some way to calculate screen orientation changes with rotation value saved in imageProxy or configuration for analysse case should be changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I got the same issue. Preview is rotated 270 degree. I also get the same rotate degree from imageProxy. Did you solve it yet